# When should I define methods on values (instead of on pointers) in Go?

Tags: go

Having defined

```
type MyInt int
```

I would like to define a method `.ShowMe()` that just prints the value. I can define this either using `*MyInt`:

```
func (this *MyInt) ShowMe() {
    fmt.Print(*this, "\n")
}
```

Or using `MyInt`:

```
func (this MyInt) ShowMe() {
    fmt.Print(this, "\n")
}
```

In what cases is it recommended to define methods on values, instead of on pointers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two questions to ask yourself when making this decision:

1. Do I want to be able to modify the receiver's value?
2. Will copying the receiver's value be expensive?

If the answer to either of these questions is yes, then define the method on a pointer.

In your example, you don't need to modify the receiver's value and copying the receiver isn't expensive.

For deciding the answer to #2, my rule of thumb is: if the receiver is a struct with more than one field, pass by pointer. Otherwise pass by value.

Comment: #2 is unfortunate, because otherwise having methods of a non-pointer is a very nice way of expressing "I won't modify the object". although I think that if I were an ideal compiler I would look at methods of a non-pointer, and determine if the object is changed at all inside the method; and if not, also emit a parallel method for the corresponding pointer type, that does the same thing but does not need to copy it

Comment: Yes, you're right: this is something a compiler could optimize. I don't believe either gc or gccgo currently do this, though, so it can be a real performance concern.

Comment: @newacct It's not really an optimisation.

Comment: If there is a copy then the method knows it has exclusive rights to that data and can act accordingly. It would be weird to have a method that expected a copy but that copy got modified by other code under it's feet.

Answer (score 7):

The [Go FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html) ([CC-licensed](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/)) has an answer:

> #### [Should I define methods on values or pointers?](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#methods_on_values_or_pointers)
>
> ```
> func (s *MyStruct) pointerMethod() { } // method on pointer
> func (s MyStruct)  valueMethod()   { } // method on value
> ```
>
> For programmers unaccustomed to pointers, the distinction between
>   these two examples can be confusing, but the situation is actually
>   very simple. When defining a method on a type, the receiver (s in the
>   above example) behaves exactly as if it were an argument to the
>   method. Whether to define the receiver as a value or as a pointer is
>   the same question, then, as whether a function argument should be a
>   value or a pointer. There are several considerations.
>
> First, and most important, does the method need to modify the
>   receiver? If it does, the receiver *must* be a pointer. (Slices and
>   maps are reference types, so their story is a little more subtle, but
>   for instance to change the length of a slice in a method the receiver
>   must still be a pointer.) In the examples above, if `pointerMethod`
>   modifies the fields of s, the caller will see those changes, but
>   `valueMethod` is called with a copy of the caller's argument (that's
>   the definition of passing a value), so changes it makes will be
>   invisible to the caller.
>
> By the way, pointer receivers are identical to the situation in Java,
>   although in Java the pointers are hidden under the covers; it's Go's
>   value receivers that are unusual.
>
> Second is the consideration of efficiency. If the receiver is large, a
>   big `struct` for instance, it will be much cheaper to use a pointer
>   receiver.
>
> Next is consistency. If some of the methods of the type must have
>   pointer receivers, the rest should too, so the method set is
>   consistent regardless of how the type is used. See [the section on
>   method sets](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#different_method_sets)
>   for details.
>
> For types such as basic types, slices, and small `structs`, a value
>   receiver is very cheap so unless the semantics of the method requires
>   a pointer, a value receiver is efficient and clear.